# Google payment method: Unable to add my debit card [ shows error - OR-CCSEH-21]

Tags: google-play, google-developers-console, google-pay

I am trying to add my VISA debit card to my payments method in Google for a couple of days now. When I try to add the card, I keep getting the following error:

> Your request failed. Use a different payment method, or contact us. [OR-CCSEH-21]

I have tried adding other debit cards too, but I still get the same error. **International transaction** is enabled in my card; in fact I can perform transactions in any other foreign/national websites, so I don't think the issue is with my card.

I have also shared the screenshot with the `Google payments` support team. They've replied that they don't have any expertise on this issue and so will assign a specialist team on my case, but it has never been assigned till now.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue? Any help will be appreciable.

Comment: I have same issue. I have no idea, whenever I add my card, It always return the same issue

Your request failed. Use a different payment method, or contact us. Learn more [OR-CCSEH-21]

Comment: Where exactly do you try to add your cards? Could you provide some screenshots?